# Spreadsheet Attributes Sorting

Tags: interface, properties

I have a (maybe) dumb question :
Is it possible to sort the spreadsheet by attribute value ?
In this example :

- Vertices are sorted by index : and i have an attribute ( Front_Pts) with -1 ,0 ,1 ,2 3 values.
- I would like to see the vertices in order 0 1 2 3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ....
- If you look at the point indices , it will be something like : 0 2 7 8 1 3 4 5 6 9 10... (Picture 1 )
- I tried to use the filter, but event here it's sorted by Index not by Value :( (picture2)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this isn't possible in the moment. But hopefully it will be in the future and the developers are very busy to improve GN. And i also think this would be a very useful feature.

Comment: Yes ! In Houdini this is super useful ! I'm gonna ask for the feature to https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot :) 
Thank you Chris !

Comment: Hop ! It's done :  https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/285v/
Let's see if people think it will be useful :)